# What is the origin of the phrase "toothless wonder" and what's the meaning of this?

Tags: etymology, phrases, phrase-requests

Google says just that "toothless wonder" is an individual in the public who is lacking a single front tooth. Well, that's logical. But what's the purpose of word "wonder" then?

If this is a slang form I can't get it, please, explain it to me. And I really want to know where it came from. All I could find out is that there were some child books named *Junie B. Jones: The Toothless Wonder*, although I am not sure that they were the origin.

Comment: Gotta be sarcasm, a wonder that you got to your position and yet pathetically impotent. Like *Aren't **you** the Girl Wonder!*

Comment: Wiktionary says [chinless wonder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chinless_wonder) is ironic, so probably the same thing here. I don't know if one inspired the other.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Railway_Signaling_and_Communications/nIbmAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=toothless+wonder&pg=PA288-IA16&printsec=frontcover

Comment: The children’s book is intended to make kids feel better about losing a front tooth.  It seems to be a popular book.

Comment: It's a relatively uncommon ***metaphoric*** usage (not a *literal* reference to a person with missing teeth). It's more often used of, for example, *organizations* - particularly, things like regulatory [Quangos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quango), officially-appointed [Ombudsmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ombudsman), and government-sponsored legal texts etc. It means they don't *actually* have the necessary (legal) powers to properly discharge their intended function.

Comment: ...a typical early use is this from opponents to the *League of Nations* (worldwide intergovernmental organisation) in 1929: [*It is a toothless wonder and we can't have anything to do with it at all.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It+is+a+toothless+wonder+and+we+can%27t%22) But it's meaningless to ask for a "first use" for something like this, since it was always capable of being used more literally, in certain relatively uncommon circumstances (not as an "idiom").

Comment: The Free Dictionary shows two meanings: 1. A person who is missing one or more teeth. 2. A person, organization, role, etc., that is utterly powerless or lacks the ability to enforce things. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/toothless+wonder%2C+a.  The meaning of "lacking enforcement powers" is first recorded 1961. https://www.etymonline.com/word/toothless

Comment: During world war two, men  prepared for service as army officers in just three months.  They were called 'ninety day wonders', and the word wonder was ironic.  A wonder is something worthy of admiration, like the seven wonders of the ancient world.

Comment: Where does Google say that, please? In what precise link?

'Chinless…' as above, I've often seen but yours is the first instance of 'toothless…' in my more than 60 years of listening